# iOS + ArcGIS SDK. `AGSPictureMarkerSymbol*` shows on simulator, but doesn't on device

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, arcgis

I can show a AGSPictureMarkerSymbol* on iOS 6.1 simulator, but when running in debug with the device (iPhone 4, iOS 6.1), even though the code is "read" and no warning or exception appears, the marker just doesn't appear. The code is the following:

```
AGSPictureMarkerSymbol* locker = [[AGSPictureMarkerSymbol alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"locker.png"];  
AGSPoint* point = [[AGSPoint alloc] initWithX:coord.x y:coord.y spatialReference:self.mapView.spatialReference];
[self.lockersLayer addGraphic:[[AGSGraphic alloc] initWithGeometry:point symbol:locker attributes:nil infoTemplateDelegate:nil]];
```

As a reference, this `self.lockersLayer` has also lots of `AGSTextSymbol*` and they show up just fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `locker.png` file. Don't know exactly what the problem was, but after changing it to another image, it started showing up on the device.